# .pkgdef-file registry entries tfs policy

Tags: tfs, registry, policy, tf-cli

I wrote an policy add-in for `tfs` with a `vsix` project, which is writing the registry-entries through a pkgdef-file. 
Until now I just had the registry-entry
`[$RootKey$\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies]`,
but when I want to use it through tf.exe I need also the entry
 `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies]`.

Is it also possible to write this entry through the `pkgdef-file` or how can I register this entry?

Comment: The problem I have is that every entry in the pkgdef file has to start with `[$RootKey$\...]`